# jQuery hide and show multiple divs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I got an html form with 3 questions, each question inside a div:

```
<div id="question1">
question1
</div>

<div id="question2">
question2
</div>

<div id="question3">
question3
</div>
```

and a button at the very end:

```
<button id="next">Next question</button>
```

What i want - only 1st div shown at first. I press the button -> 2nd div loads, 1st div hides. I press the button one more time -> 2nd div hides, 3rd div shows up.

Here is how i tried:

```
<script>
$('#question2').hide();
$('#question3').hide();

    $("#next").click(function (e) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('#question1').hide();
        $('#question2').show();
    });
</script>
```

I dont know how to load the 3rd div.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
$('div[id^="question"]').hide().first().show();

$("#next").click(function (e) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('div[id^="question"]:visible').hide().next().show();
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/qYyPA/)

Answer (score 6):

You can simply look for the first visible `div`, and hide it, subsequently showing the next `div`:

```
var next;
$("#advance").on("click", function () {
    next = $("#steps div:visible:first").hide().next();
    next.length ? next.show() : alert( "No more divs" );
});
```

I made one minor suggestion; nest your `divs` into a common container:

```
<button id="advance">Advance</button>
<div id="steps">
    <div id="question1">question1</div>
    <div id="question2">question2</div>
    <div id="question3">question3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like:

EDIT: Added jsfiddle demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/KPjUc/

```
 var currentQuestion = 1; 

 $("#next").click(function (e) {
       //hide all div's start with "question"
        $("div[id^=question]").hide();

       //Show div related to current question number
        $('#question' + currentQuestion++).show();
       //When last question is reached, move back to first question
          if(currentQuestion >3){
               currentQuestion =1;
         }
    });
```

Maybe not 100% complete or correct, but you get the idea...

Comment: Forgot to mention that this is scalable to unlimited question, and you can easily implement previous and next buttons this way

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this

http://jsfiddle.net/2dJAN/7/

```
<div id="question1">
question1
</div>
<div id="question2">
question2
</div>
<div id="question3">
question3
</div>
<button id="next">Next question</button>

$('#question2').hide();
$('#question3').hide();

    $("#next").click(function (e) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('#question1').hide();
        $('#question2').show();
        $(this).on("click",function(){
        $('#question2').hide();
        $('#question3').show();
      });  
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check wich question is visible before deciding what to do when the button is clicked.

```
<script>
$('#question2').hide();
$('#question3').hide();

    $("#next").click(function (e) {
        event.preventDefault();
        if ($('#question1').is(':visible')) {
                $('#question1').hide();
                $('#question2').show();
        } else if ($('#question2').is(':visible')) {
                $('#question2').hide();
                $('#question3').show();
                .html('Save');
        } else if ($('#question3').is(':visible')) {
                 //Submit
        }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <div id="question1" class="question">
    question1
    </div>

    <div id="question2" class="question">
    question2
    </div>

    <div id="question3" class="question">
    question3
    </div>......



$("#next").click(function (e) {
    $('.question').hide();
    var current_q_id = $(this).attr('id');
    // question counter 
    var current_no = current_q_id.replace("question", ""); // 1 , 2 ,3 
    var next_no = parseInt(current_no) + 1;
    // generate next div id 
    var next_div_id = '#question'+next_no;

    // show next div
    $(next_div_id).show();
});
```

this will work for more that 3 div. you can add max counter and add code to stop processing when end reached.